# Dropzone.js - visuals are not displayed correctly

Tags: error-handling, icons, dropzone.js

The confirmation icons (valid and error) of my dropzone are not displayed anymore :

[image]

Did somebody get a fix or a clue to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Try this configuration.

```js
var accept = ".png";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", { 
  url: "/file/post",
   acceptedFiles: accept,
   uploadMultiple: false,
   createImageThumbnails: false,
   addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
        this.removeAllFiles();
        this.addFile(file);
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clsbox-1" runat="server"  >
  <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone">

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank for reply. However I tried your config and the icons are still not displayed properly, even in the snippet

Comment: @Reign.85 Please check your syntax Because it's run perfectly with this code. you can check via 'Run Code Snippet"